# How to Run a function again i'm creating a chatbot for project?

Tags: python, project, chatbot

```
def chatbot(n):
     if n=="ARE U REAL?" or n=="are u real?" or n=="are you real" or n=="are you real" or n=="Are you real?" or n=="are u real":
         print("BOT: YES")
     elif n=="What's your name?" or n=='what is your name?' or n=='whats your name?' or n=='whats your name':
         print("BOT: My name is ChatBot :)")
     elif n=="":
         print("Ask something")
     else:
         print("BOT: Sorry :( I can't respond to that,Try asking another question.")
print("BOT: HEY IM CHATBOT MAY I KNOW YOUR NAME?")
a=input('YOU:')
print("BOT: Hi",a.upper())
print("BOT: ASK ME SOMETHING :)")
n=input("YOU:").lower()
#PRINT("BOT: ASK ME AGAIN") 
#N=INPUT("YOU:")SHOULD BE DONE AFTER THE ABOVE ONE HAS COMPLETED
chatbot(n)
```

I want a conversational-type chatbot for response and checking that response easily. I'm a beginner and I want the code to be easy.

Comment: And what is going wrong with your attempt so far? I'm not clear what you need help with.

Comment: nothing is going wrong i want it the code to run again not the whole code but just i want the code to take the input again and check the conditions again and give an output, basically a follow up conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop

```
def chatbot(n):
    if n=="ARE U REAL?" or n=="are u real?" or n=="are you real" or n=="are you real" or n=="Are you real?" or n=="are u real":
        print("BOT: YES")
    elif n=="What's your name?" or n=='what is your name?' or n=='whats your name?' or n=='whats your name':
        print("BOT: My name is ChatBot :)")
    elif n=="":
        print("Ask something")
    else:
        print("BOT: Sorry :( I can't respond to that,Try asking another question.")
print("BOT: HEY IM CHATBOT MAY I KNOW YOUR NAME?")
a=input('YOU:')
print("BOT: Hi",a.upper())

while True:
    print("BOT: ASK ME SOMETHING :)")
    n=input("YOU:").lower()
    if n != 'q':
        chatbot(n)
    else:
        print("BOT: BYE :)")
        break
```

It will keep repeating until you enter `q`.